# Can I use Fabric to perform interactive shell commands?

Tags: python, shell, interactive, fabric

I`m trying to use [fabric](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Fabric/0.9.4) to install and deploy a web project during which I need to create a postgresql database and configure a RabbitMQ server. Both these operations are interactive and requires input from the user for creating a database, adding a user, setting password etc ( at least to my knowledge ).

Can I use a fabric script to do interative shell operations like these?

Comment: Do you know Expect? Take a look at http://www.noah.org/wiki/pexpect

Comment: Most (well made) installers will have a way to avoid interactive questions, or at least provide configuration to script the answers. It may be more advantageous to look into that, before getting into `expect` or `pexpect`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is in Fabric 1.0. I've tried it and it works for me.

> Older versions of Fabric (and similar high level SSH libraries) run remote programs in limbo, unable to be touched from the local end. This is problematic when you have a serious need to enter passwords or otherwise interact with the remote program.
>
> Fabric 1.0 and later breaks down this wall and ensures you can always talk to the other side.

[Source](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.0.0/tutorial.html#remote-interactivity)

*Edit*: As payne notes below, Fabric 1.0 was released. I edited the answer to indicate this.

Comment: And Fabric 1.0 was released on Mar 6.