# How to interact with installer on remote host using Fabric and Python

Tags: python, installation, interactive, fabric

I use fabric to run an installer on remote host

def test():
        run("sh /opt/foo.bin")
The output looks like:

[user@remoteHost:22] out: PRESS  TO CONTINUE:

..........

During the installation i need to press Enter several times and input some info.
Are there any possibility to automate this operations (press  and input text info) using Fabric?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you're looking more for [pxepect](http://www.noah.org/wiki/pexpect), but you can use this module and it's functionality inside fabric tasks. It's just that Fabric doesn't keep state, and also doesn't have functionality to interact with prompts in a scripted way. It expects the user to interact, in those cases.

Comment: Could you give us also some example use within Fabric?

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10483096/708221 or here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10007635/708221

Comment: thanks for the work, and example. In this specific use case, `yes | cmd`, might work simpler, but cool stuff all around.