# How to answer to prompts automatically with python fabric?

Tags: python, command-prompt, fabric

I want to run a command which prompts me to enter yes/no or y/n or whatever. If I just run the command `local("my_command")` then it stops and asks me for input. When I type what is needed, script continues to work. How can I automatically respond to the prompt?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get Fabric to automatically (instead of user-interactively) interact with shell commands? Combine with pexpect?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8291380/how-to-get-fabric-to-automatically-instead-of-user-interactively-interact-with)

Comment: @aemdy could you please change the answer to be the one suggested by Timothée Jeannin. I have seen several other questions like this, and the currently selected answer is outdated. It would make it much easier for folks to get the right answer :).

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Starting from version `1.9`, Fabric includes a way of managing this properly.

The [section about Prompts](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.9/usage/env.html#prompts) in the Fabric documentation says:

> The prompts dictionary allows users to control interactive prompts. If
>   a key in the dictionary is found in a command’s standard output
>   stream, Fabric will automatically answer with the corresponding
>   dictionary value.

You should be able to make Fabric automatically answer prompts like this:

```
with settings(prompts={'Do you want to continue [Y/n]? ': 'Y'}):
    run('apt-get update')
    run('apt-get upgrade')
```

Comment: Pretty sure this should be the unofficially accepted answer.

Comment: @aemdy This should really be the accepted answer at this point, works out of the box with no issues.

Comment: Tip:  Your prompts dictionary keys are matched using a built-in Fabric function io._endswith.  If you can't figure out why your patterns aren't matching, it might be because you forgot to include a space at the end.  For example "UNIX password: " or "New password: " or "Retype new password: "

Comment: I get `NameError: global name 'settings' is not defined`

Comment: I'm struggling to figure out how I could use this to, first, trigger a sequence of actions, and only *then* reply to the prompt. Is there any way?

Comment: Fabric uses `.endswith` for its check, so make sure you include trailing spaces in the string you use as a key in the `prompts` dictionary.

Comment: I find that there is a white space after '[Y/n]? ', is it necessary or not?

Comment: Does this work with `local()` function? I tried something simple, like `with settings(prompts={'Continue? ': 'Y'}): local('read -p "Continue? " var', capture=True)` and it was blocked on the prompt. Update: It looks like input was still connected to console :(

Comment: To answer my own question from above, it looks like prompts are handled in ssh io while `local` is just a simple wrapper on top of `Popen` so this won't work. I guess we need to use `pexpect`.

Answer (score 23):

I have used simple echo pipes to answer prompts with Fabric.

```
run('echo "yes\n"| my_command')
```

Comment: You can also use the `yes` command: `run("yes | my_command")`

Comment: heads up for the `yes`!

Answer (score 13):

**Note: this answer is several years old, and in the mean time fabric has (interestingly similar looking) implementation of this. See the answer by @timothée-jeannin below.**

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/10007635/708221

`pip install fexpect`

```
from ilogue.fexpect import expect, expecting, run 

prompts = []
prompts += expect('What is your name?','John')
prompts += expect('Are you at stackoverflow?','Yes')

with expecting(prompts):
    run('my_command')
```

[Fexpect adds answering to prompts to fabric with use of pexpect](http://ilogue.com/jasper/blog/fexpect--dealing-with-prompts-in-fabric-with-pexpect/)

Comment: Cool project, but it'd be better if it could not have to rely on putting a python file on the server. Need to check this out more and see if I can assist.

Comment: Thanks Morgan, I agree. I have suggested something on the fabric list, but got no response so far, and ended up writing fexpect which cost me less time than getting into the internals of Fabric.

Comment: Right, I think I saw that, but didn't perhaps grok the intent. I'm pretty interested in pushing this further, and have had some experience in Fabric internals, and before I found Fabric, pxssh/pexpect.

Comment: Ok, let me know if I can be of assistance

Comment: it doesnt work for me: http://pastebin.com/vAPwVxaR
code: http://pastebin.com/HFUJkb6J

Comment: Please post this as a new question and send it to me. Also include your python code if possible

Comment: The blog post link currently unavailable, "ilogue.com is for sale"... Here's the archived page: http://web.archive.org/web/20140624141333/http://ilogue.com/jasper/blog/fexpect--dealing-with-prompts-in-fabric-with-pexpect/

Comment: Yet another dependency on a dead project? Yuck.

Comment: Fabric has awesome built in support for this now. Check a few comments down for the 31 point answer.

Comment: @Breedly I have added a note to this answer as a heads up for visitors

Answer (score 5):

In [Fabric 2.1](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/2.1/), this can be accomplished using the [auto-respond example](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/2.1/getting-started.html?highlight=watchers#superuser-privileges-via-auto-response) that is available through the invoke package (a dependency of Fabric 2.1):

```
>>> from invoke import Responder
>>> from fabric import Connection
>>> c = Connection('host')
>>> sudopass = Responder(
...     pattern=r'\[sudo\] password:',
...     response='mypassword\n',
... )
>>> c.run('sudo whoami', pty=True, watchers=[sudopass])
[sudo] password:
root
<Result cmd='sudo whoami' exited=0>
```

Note that this is not limited to sudo passwords and can be used anywhere where you have a pattern to match for and a canned response (that may not be a password).

There are a couple of tips:

1. `pty=True` is **NOT** necessary but could be important because it makes the flow seem more realistic. e.g. if you had a prompt expecting a **yes/no** answer to proceed, without it(`pty=True`) your command would still run; **except**, your choice/input(specified by `response`) **won't be shown as typed** as the answer as one might expect
2. The `pattern` specified within the `Responder` can often include spaces at the end of the line so try adding spaces when the `watcher` doesn't seem to match.
3. According to the note discussed at the end of the [watcher docs](http://docs.pyinvoke.org/en/latest/concepts/watchers.html):

   *The pattern argument to Responder is treated as a regular expression, requiring more care (note how we had to escape our square-brackets in the above example) but providing more power as well.*

   So, don't forget to escape (using backslashes) where necessary.

Answer (score 4):

To expand a bit on [Timothée's excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25378036/456550), here's [the code](https://github.com/fabric/fabric/blob/5d2e61cc78fe7a86f8ef4c6a167d7207ac1c4839/fabric/io.py) that Fabric uses when checking the `prompts` dictionary.

```
def _get_prompt_response(self):
    """
    Iterate through the request prompts dict and return the response and
    original request if we find a match
    """
    for tup in env.prompts.iteritems():
        if _endswith(self.capture, tup[0]):
            return tup
    return None, None
```

Fabric uses `.endswith` for its check, so make sure you include trailing spaces in the string you use as a key in the `prompts` dictionary.

For example - let's say you are trying to automate the Django test database prompt

> Type 'yes' if you would like to try deleting the test database 'test_my_app', or 'no' to cancel:

All we need is enough of the end of the prompt so that it is unique. Include trailing spaces.

```
django_test_database_prompt = "or 'no' to cancel: "
#         won't work without this trailing space ^

with settings(
    prompts={django_test_database_prompt : 'yes'}
):
    run('%s %s' % (virtualenv_python_path,
                   test_runner_file_path,
                  )
       )
```

Answer (score 2):

Putting this as an answer though its a comment from @BobNadler

run("yes | my_command");