# How to respond to possible prompt in fabric?

Tags: python, fabric

When I login to one of our servers I'm prompted with:

```
Please select the system to work with:
   1: system1 (user u1)
   2: system2 (user u1)
   3: system3 (user u2)

Enter your choice (1-3) [1]:
```

and I need to enter "1" **before** any command is to be executed, **right after login**.
Can I automatically respond via fabric to such prompts? Other boxes could have login without prompt, so it's only one of the possible situations. Something like this is desired:

```
if prompt("Enter your choice (1-3) [1]:"):
  response("1")
run(command)
```

How can this be done? I read [Interaction with remote programs](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/latest/usage/interactivity.html), however didn't find any useful example. i'd prefer to use only fabric, not to involve another modules if it's possible.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to answer to prompts automatically with python fabric?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10479078/how-to-answer-to-prompts-automatically-with-python-fabric)

Answer (score 1):

Seems, no way.

Possible solutions are following:

1. Some command-line tools supports flag that suppresses prompts placing default values instead (if it's what you need).
2. You can use [*autoexpect* tool](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/3065) that was proposed as possible solution in [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4857702/how-to-provide-password-to-a-command-that-prompts-for-one-in-bash).

Comment: "supports flag that suppresses prompts" - it's not about this one :) server prompts it each login