# automatic docker login within a bash script

Tags: linux, bash, unix, docker

How can I preseed my credentials to `docker login` command within a script ?

I'm using a bash script that basically automates the whole process of setting up my custom VMs etc, but when I need to login to docker within the script to pull the images, I get the following error:

> Username: FATA[0000] inappropriate ioctl for device

The command I was using is the following:

```
( echo "xxx"; echo "yyy"; echo "zzz" ) | docker login docker.somesite.org
```

Is this possible to achieve without using and coping over an existing `.dockercfg` file and how,

Many thanks.

Comment: You'll have to use expect/pexpect

Answer (score 113, accepted):

### Docker 18 and beyond

There's now an [officially-documented](https://docs.docker.com/reference/cli/docker/login/#password-stdin) way to do this:

```
cat ~/my_password.txt | docker login --username foo --password-stdin
```

### Docker 1.11 through Docker 17

You can pass all the arguments on the command-line:

```
docker login --username=$DOCKER_USER --password=$DOCKER_PASS $DOCKER_HOST
```

If you don't specify `DOCKER_HOST`, you'll get the main Docker repo. If you leave out any of the arguments, you'll be prompted for that argument.

### Older than 1.11

The same path as just above, except that you need to *also* pass an `--email` flag. The contents of this are not actually checked, so anything is fine:

```
docker login --username=$DOCKER_USER --password=$DOCKER_PASS $DOCKER_HOST --email whale@docker.com
```

Comment: Short notation might be more convenient:
`docker login -u $DOCKER_USER -p $DOCKER_PASS -m $DOCKER_EMAIL $DOCKER_HOST`

Comment: It's a matter of preference, but when I'm writing a script I prefer long options because it's self-documenting and there's no advantage to terseness. (As opposed to on the command line where it's saving my fingers and avoiding wrapping.)

Comment: Passing the password on the command line is insecure, but so far I haven't been able to find an alternative.

Comment: @JasonHeiss you could log in manually, then get the token, then create the `~/.docker/config.json` file yourself. But Docker Hub doesn't really have a system for creating and destroying tokens for programmatic use.

Comment: As of Docker 1.11.0, using `--email` is deprecated; and will be removed in 1.14. Above example still valid minus that argument.

Comment: You should never use "--password" since that will expose the password to logfiles in case of a DockerHub API error and will also make it visible to other processes. Instead, use "--password-stdin"

Comment: Now that Docker gives a warning about storing the password unencrypted on the machine, is it possible do do an unattended docker login in case of having a credentials store set up for it? Currently it asks for the passphrase of the GPG private key if using `pass` on Linux. Can the passphrase be provided somehow without user intervention?

Comment: instead of password, generate an access token in https://hub.docker.com/ -> Settings -> Security

Answer (score 18):

https://docs.docker.com/reference/cli/docker/login/#password-stdin

> To run the `docker login` command non-interactively, you can set the `--password-stdin` flag to provide a password through `STDIN`. Using `STDIN` prevents the password from ending up in the shell's history, or log-files.

```bash
echo $DOCKER_PASS | docker login -u$DOCKER_USER --password-stdin $DOCKER_HOST
```

Answer (score 8):

When you login to your private registry, docker auto create a file $HOME/.docker/config.json The file had the Credentials info, so you could save the file and copy to any host when you want to login the registry.

The file content like this:

```
{
     "auths": {
                   "example.com": {
                                    "auth": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
                    }
            }
 }
```

Add-on If you want to login multi docker registry on one server ,just add another auth info.like this:

```
{
     "auths": {
                   "example.com": {
                                    "auth": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
                    },
                    "example1.com":{
                                    "auth": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
                    }
            }
 }
```

Now you can push and pull images from the example.com and example1.com.

Comment: It stil shows 

Authenticating with existing credentials...
WARNING! Your password will be stored unencrypted in /home/user/.docker/config.json.
Configure a credential helper to remove this warning. See
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login/#credentials-store

Are you sure you want to proceed? [y/N]

Comment: Thanks to Henri Siponen answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10479078/how-to-answer-to-prompts-automatically-with-python-fabric  I was able to fix it by adding :   
echo "y" |  docker login myregistry.com

Answer (score 2):

For any random passer by that may stumble into this looking for a way to use this against an Openshift environment's container registry (Docker) you can use the following to provide the registry URI along with the credentials to log into it using an Openshift token.

```
$ echo "$(oc whoami -t)" | docker login -u $USER --password-stdin \
    $(oc get route docker-registry -n default --no-headers | awk '{print $2}')
Login Succeeded
```

The above does 3 things:

- Passes token retrieved from Openshift `oc whoami -t`
- Determines Openshift's registry URI

  ```
  $(oc get route docker-registry -n default --no-headers | awk '{print $2}'`)
  ```
- Logs into registry using `$USER` + token from above

Answer (score 0):

I was having massive issues with this, just wanted to add that the environment variable `DOCKER_HOST` has special meaning to docker to define the daemon socket it connects to, causing it to fail login. There's a full list of the environment variables docker uses here: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cli/

I changed my environment variables to something else, e.g. `REG_` and it worked

```
docker login --username $REG_USERNAME --password $REG_PASSWORD $REG_HOST
```

Note, if you're doing this in a gitlab runner, there's no need to use the `--password-stdin` flag if you're already using variable masking (you can, there's just no need).