# Python fabric respond to prompts in output

Tags: python, ssh, fabric

I have two problems I am trying to solve with fabric for python.

1. I'd like to auto-enter the password at the prompt:

   - [fabric password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2339735/fabric-password)
2. I'd like to auto-respond to prompts based on the output of a session:

   - [How to answer to prompts automatically with python fabric?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10479078/how-to-answer-to-prompts-automatically-with-python-fabric)

Both of these should be possible as the above links show, but I can't get them to work. When I run the following file via `fab test`

```
from fabric.api import run, env, settings

env.hosts = ['<user>@<host>']
env.passwords = {'<user>@<host>': '<password>'}

def test():
    with settings(prompts={"Please select a menu item: ": "1",}):
        return
    run("ls")
```

My output is:

```
[<user>@<host>] Login password for '<user>':
```

At which point I have to type my password, **instead of auto-entering**. Then per the remote host I get a menu which I want to auto respond to, but **my prompt's auto-complete doesn't work**.

```
[<user>@<host>] out: <a menu>
[<user>@<host>] out: Please select a menu item:
```

What do I need to do to get this to auto-enter my password and auto-answer this prompt?

Comment: Hello did you understand how to resolve your problem?

Comment: No luck. I'd still love to know how.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the documentation on [env.passwords](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.13/usage/env.html#passwords) it says:

> This dictionary is largely for internal use, and is filled
>   automatically as a per-host-string password cache. Keys are full host
>   strings and values are passwords (strings).

The important note is the warning following the above:

> **Warning**
>
> If you modify or generate this dict manually, you must use
>   fully qualified host strings with user and port values. See the link
>   above for details on the host string API.

Following the above warning, make sure that the hostname is FQDN and perhaps even add the port number `:22` and see if it works.

As for the prompt, that should have worked as long as you ran the command *inside* the `with` block (which I can't tell from your sample code). Also check if the prompt is followed by a space, if not remove it from your `prompts` key.